# Create HTML Table using PHP stdClass Object

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like bellow,

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => test p1 [structurename] => test structure [taskname] => task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 10.00 [hours] => 5.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-03 07:38:08 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => test p1 [structurename] => test structure [taskname] => task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 10.00 [hours] => 2.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 14:21:34 )
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => p2 [structurename] => struc [taskname] => p2t1 [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-03 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 8.00 [hours] => 2.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 11:05:31 )
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => p2 [structurename] => struc [taskname] => p2t1 [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-03 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 8.00 [hours] => 6.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-05 08:00:22 )
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => web dev [structurename] => dev test [taskname] => dev task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-04 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 30.00 [hours] => 8.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 08:21:14 ))
```

and **I want your help to create the following HTML table** output using the above array,

[image]

The idea is to show worked hours for a given task in a certain week period (in this case first week of February, 2016).
According to the above array, [hours] is the worked hours and [createdon] is the day worked hours.

for an example,

test p1   |   test structure   |   task - has two arrays ( [0] => stdClass Object and [ 1 ] => stdClass Object ) in the above stdClass object and since they are represents the same Task of given Project they should be in one row in the HTML Table.

**02-01 | 02-02 | 02-03 | 02-04 | 02-05** are the dates (February first week)
and I am using another array for the dates as bellow

```
Array ( [0] => 2016-02-01
        [1] => 2016-02-02
        [2] => 2016-02-03
        [3] => 2016-02-04
        [4] => 2016-02-05 )
```

**Further I have tried it as below** but it does not giving me the expected output.

```
<table id="filter_table4" class="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project | Structure | <b>Task</b></th>
                <th>Start Date, Time</th>
                <th>Estimated<br />Hours</th>
                <?php
                  foreach( $dates as $date )
                  {
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
                    echo '<th>'. $date->format("m-d") .'</th>';
                  }
                ?>
                <th>Progress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
              foreach( $week_tasks as $task )
              {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'. $task->projectname .' | '. $task->structurename .' | <b>'. $task->taskname .'</b></td>
                        <td>'. $task->taskstartdate .'</td>
                        <td>'. $task->estimatedhours .'</td>
                        <td> '. $task->hours .' </td>
                        <td> '. $task->hours .' </td>
                        <td> '. $task->hours .' </td>
                        <td> '. $task->hours .' </td>
                        <td> '. $task->hours .' </td>
                        <td>
                            '. $progress .'
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
              }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And thanks in advance.

Comment: test this and let me know the status `foreach($arr as $val){
    $a = get_object_vars($val);
 ?><tr><?php
 foreach($a as $v ){
     echo '<td>$v</td>';
 }
 ?>
 </tr>
 <?php
}`

Comment: Hi. it gives something like this http://prnt.sc/afgfx5 and thanks for your hand :))

Comment: try this that was my foolishness `foreach($arr as $val){ $a = get_object_vars($val); ?><tr><?php foreach($a as $v ){ echo '<td>' . $v . '</td>'; } ?> </tr> <?php }` .

Comment: It gives me this http://prnt.sc/afgfx5 and it is little bit different than expected.

Comment: now this `foreach($arr as $val){ $a = get_object_vars($val); ?><tr><?php foreach($a as $v ){ echo "<td>"; var_dump($v);  echo "</td>" } ?> </tr> <?php }`

Comment: This is the result for the above last one http://prnt.sc/afgmea

Comment: now `foreach($arr as $val){ $a = get_object_vars($val); ?><tr><?php foreach($a as $v ){ echo "<td>"; echo $v; echo "</td>" } ?> </tr> <?php }`

Comment: after this you can arrange it as per your requirement , I am posting an answer upvote is if you find it helpful and update me the status, so that I can help you achieving it by updating my answer.

Comment: Again something like previous http://prnt.sc/afgnvx this should be in one line :)

Comment: yes, I just replace the var_dump with echo. next move to my answer.I will modify that.

Comment: are you ok with modification in table structure or you want to modify the array ?

Comment: I want to modify the array and get this http://prnt.sc/afgrzj out put

Comment: I need to know how it is produced, so it is again a big part, so if you think still now, my answer is helpful, upvote it or accept and post another question. or I am leaving this session here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want if combination of projectname, structurename and taskname comes again it should skip the row. 
Try this code

```
    <?php
$array_new  = array();
$i = 0;
  foreach( $week_tasks as $task )
  {
    $search_string = $task->projectname .' | '. $task->structurename .' | '. $task->taskname;

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
    $md = $date->format("m-d");
    if(!isset($array_new[$search_string]))
    {
        $array_new[$search_string]['name'] = $task->projectname .' | '. $task->structurename .' | <b>'. $task->taskname .'</b>'; 
        $array_new[$search_string]['taskstartdate'] = $task->taskstartdate;
        $array_new[$search_string]['estimatedhours'] = $task->estimatedhours;
    }

    $array_new[$search_string]['hours'][$md] = $task->hours; 

  }
  $html ='';
  foreach( $array_new as $row )
  {
        $html .= '<tr>
            <td>'. $row['name'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['taskstartdate'] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row['estimatedhours'] .'</td>';

        foreach( $dates as $date )
        {
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);
           $md = $date->format("m-d");
           if(isset($row[$md])){
            $html.='<td> '. $row[$md] .' </td>';
           }else{
                $html.='<td> </td>';
           }
        }

       $html .='<td>
                '. $progress .'
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. yes this combine projectname, structurename and taskname also I want to show the worked hours in the same row that comes with other rows while skipping them.

Comment: If ypu can refer the image I have attached. You might be able to understand what I am saying :)) and I appreciate your hand for this

Comment: @jitendra, your answer is only good for this and if he needs to change in future, it will not work.so I will suggest you to do it i  better way, for now, I can upvote it.